# Convert array of Objects to an Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I know this has been asked before, but every solution I found isn't doing it the way I need it.

The Array

```
[ {key: "Title", value: "Default Text"}, {key: "Title2", value: "Default Text2"} ]
```

Object I Need

```
{
"Title": "Default Text", 
"Title2": "Default Text2"
}
```

Everything I try seems to return this which is wrong:

```
{ {key: "Title", value: "Default Text"}, {key: "Title2", value: "Default Text2"} }
```

I've tried most things I found here on SO.. the last one I've tried that is formatting it wrong is:

```
let obj = Object.assign({}, arrayHere);
```

What I want:

[image: WHat I need]

What I keep getting, but is wrong:

[image: What I keep getting, but is wrong]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [***Array.prototype.reduce()***](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function:

```js
var arr = [ {key: "Title", value: "Default Text"}, {key: "Title2", value: "Default Text2"} ],
    result = arr.reduce((r,o) => {r[o.key] = o.value; return r; }, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: ok let me try brb

Comment: IT WORKED THANK YOU

Comment: @user1189352, you're welcome

Answer (score 1):

You could assign the single created objects with [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

```js
var array = [{ key: "Title", value: "Default Text" }, { key: "Title2", value: "Default Text2" }];
    object = Object.assign({}, ...array.map(o => ({ [o.key]: o.value })));
    
console.log(object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const a = [ {key: "Title", value: "Default Text"}, {key: "Title2", value: "Default Text2"} ];

function convertArr(arr) {
    const res = {};

    a.forEach((item) => 
       res[item.key] = item.value;
    })
    return res;
}

convertArr(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Array.prototype.map(),

```
var Object = [ {key: "Title", value: "Default Text"}, {key: "Title2", value: "Default Text2"} ];

var result = Object.map(function(obj) {
             var rObj = {};
             rObj[obj.key] = obj.value;
             return rObj; });
```